# How to search for empty emails in Apple mail?

Tags: email

How can I filter email messages with no content in Apple mail?

Answer (score 1):

- It's not possible to make a rule with an empty field in Mail.app on OS X apparently. The solution I found is to list all vowels as necessarily missing in order to process the message (in this example case, move it to the trash).
- Note: this does not deal with images or attachments of any type as the sole content of the message body however. An attachment *does* count as 'content' in the message body. The rule(s) and criteria would have to be quite extensive to deal with attachments in addition to non-character message content.
- See image:

[image]